# Why doesn't nginx serve my 404 page under vagrant?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, ansible

I have a static HTML site with a 404 page at /404/index.html. Vagrant is mapping port 80 to 9000 so I access my site at `http://localhost:9000`. The site is browsable, but if I try to force a 404 error I'm seeing /index.html instead. I've tried following a bunch of tutorials, but it always ends up showing the index page.

If I do `vagrant ssh` I have the same experience. The only difference is that I can do `curl http://localhost/404/` and see the 404 page's content. Ansible is expanding the values of the `{{ }}` template items during provisioning.

**default (site template)**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root {{ web_root }};
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from `http://localhost/`
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    error_page 400 404 /404/index.html;
    location = /404/index.html {
        root {{ web_root }};
    }



    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes {{ ansible_processor_count }};

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections {{ connections }} ;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # If HTTPS, then set a variable so it can be passed along.
    ##

    map $scheme $server_https {
        default off;
        https on;
    }

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I haven't messed around with different 404 pages, but having `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` and getting `index.html` is what I would expect.

Try changing to `try_files $uri $uri/ /404/index.html;`

Comment: Thanks that was it. This seems like a neat config feature, but it makes me wonder whether it is too smart ;)